# Segmentation fault of Bacula on Apline Linux

Tags: linux, bacula, segmentation-fault, alpine

I'm trying to run Bacula (backup app) on Apline Linux and get segmentation fault when connecting thru *bconsole* to *bacula-dir*.
I was tried working configuration from another non-Alpine server, clean configuration from Alpine latest-stable and from Alpine edge but with no success.

Here is exactly error output with traceback

```
# /usr/sbin/bacula-dir -f -d 99 -m -T
bacula-dir: dird.c:219-0 Debug level = 99
Bacula interrupted by signal 11: Segmentation violation
Kaboom! bacula-dir, build-3-15-x86_64-dir got signal 11 - Segmentation violation at 03-Apr-2022 17:26:08. Attempting traceback.
Kaboom! exepath=/usr/sbin/
Calling: /usr/sbin/btraceback /usr/sbin/bacula-dir 2324 /var/lib/bacula
Segmentation fault
The btraceback call returned 139
LockDump: /var/lib/bacula/bacula.2324.traceback

 ==== Traceback output ====

[New LWP 2325]
[New LWP 2326]
[New LWP 2329]
0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#2  0x00007fe3ebce4b84 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 4 (LWP 2329 "bacula-dir"):
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#2  0x00007fe3eb5a6b74 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 3 (LWP 2326 "bacula-dir"):
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#2  0x00007fe3eb5cdb74 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (LWP 2325 "bacula-dir"):
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#2  0x00007fe3eb5f0b74 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (LWP 2324 "bacula-dir"):
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#2  0x00007fe3ebce4b84 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#0  0x00007fe3ebca3413 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fe3ebca072d in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fe3ebce4b84 in ?? () from /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
[Inferior 1 (process 2324) detached]
Attempt to dump current JCRs. njcrs=1
threadid=0x7fe3ebce4b48 JobId=0 JobStatus=R jcr=0x7fe3eb608318 name=*JobMonitor*.2022-04-03_17.26.05_01
        use_count=1 killable=0
        JobType=I JobLevel=
        sched_time=03-Apr-2022 17:26 start_time=03-Apr-2022 17:26
        end_time=01-Jan-1970 03:00 wait_time=01-Jan-1970 03:00
        db=0 db_batch=0 batch_started=0
        wstore=0x7fe3ebc04c58 rstore=0 wjcr=0 client=0x7fe3ebc04ac8 reschedule_count=0 SD_msg_chan_started=0
List plugins. Hook count=0
 ==== End traceback output ====

Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved in the fresh musl-1.2.3-r0 at April 7, 2022 (still in Edge branch)